# Custom Accuracy is very slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have custom accuracy function for my tensorflow network.  Currently its running very slow because of it and I cant figure out how to condense the code to speed it up.  I've looked at other solutions but given the parameters I set I don't think I can use anything that exists to get the desired values. Is there anything in my code that is grossly wrong and should be condensed? Im just looking for vague suggestions to speed it up not for one to rewrite all my code unless its super simple to condense to like a single line.

data values are tensors with values between 0 and 1.  This code is designed to only notice when true values are one, what the accuracy is for that value, or when the predicted is non-zero and the true is zero.  but when true and predicted are zero, it is ignored for the overall accuracy.

I wonder if its possible to make a math equation that defines the above constraints that applies to the entire tensor?  is that what I should try and make?

```
def Accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
  if y_true.get_shape() != y_pred.get_shape():
    raise 'Exception: y_true and y_pred must be the same shape'
  if len(y_true.shape)>1:
    nested_accuracy=[NoteAccuracy(yt_unit, yp_unit) for yt_unit, yp_unit in zip(y_true, y_pred)]
    return (sum(nested_accuracy)/len(nested_accuracy))
  else:
    counter=0
    true_watcher=[]
    false_watcher=[]
    for yt_unit, yp_unit in zip(y_true, y_pred):
      if yt_unit > 0:
        true_watcher.append(abs(yp_unit-yt_unit))
        counter+=1
      else:
        if yp_unit > 0.10:
          false_watcher.append(abs(yp_unit-yt_unit))
          counter+=1
    if counter == 0:
      return 1
    else:
      if len(true_watcher) != 0 and len(false_watcher) != 0:
        return (sum(true_watcher)/len(true_watcher))*(sum(false_watcher)/len(false_watcher))
      elif len(true_watcher) != 0:
        return (sum(true_watcher)/len(true_watcher))
      elif len(false_watcher) != 0:
        return (sum(false_watcher)/len(false_watcher))
```

what makes this run so slow compared to other keras metrics?  How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [list comprehensions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) instead of the for loop?

Also you could use [enumerate](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/) instead of the counter.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to apply Numpy arrays with masking then performing the operations across the entire tensor at once.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Tensorflow backend for the calculations,
I think it's the use of pythonic builtins that is slowing the process.
A Simple Example would be:

```py
# With Tensorflow
def Accuracy(y_pred, y_true):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.round(y_pred), tf.cast(y_true, tf.int64))
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32), axis=-1)

# With Keras
def Accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, y_pred))
```